# Strange behaviour with getIntegerv() and std::cout

Tags: c++, opengl, output, iostream, undefined-behavior

This code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLint version;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &version);
    std::cout << version << std::endl;
    //(Un)comment the next line
    //std::cout << "" << version << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
32766
```

or

```
0
0
```

when the line is commented or uncommented, respectively.
I know that you have to init glfw and glew libraries before using some methods(with glfw initialized this still happening), but... How is possible that the previous line change its behavior commenting or uncommenting the next line? The machine goes to the past and execute the previous line? omg

PS: I know what is an "undefined behavior" but that doesn't mean that you can break the laws of physics, travel to the past and modify the behavior of some methods.

Comment: Repeat after me: undefined behaviour is *undefined*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that you have to init glew libraries before using some methods, but... How is possible that the previous line change its behavior commenting or uncommenting the next line?

Because this is what the "undefined" in *undefined behavior* means.

When you call a GL function without a current GL context, anything can happen. So you have undefined behavior from the GL side here. However, in the real world, most implementations will just do *nothing* in that case, so `version` does not get written to, and you are printing the content of an *uninitialized* variable, so you have undefined behavior on the C++ side then. In the real world, you most likely print some contents of your stack, and by changing the code, you are changing the compiled result.

Comment: I know what is an "undefined beavior". But my question is: How is it possible that an undefined behavior breaks the laws of physics and causes a space-time rupture causing the previous line to change its behavior?

Comment: It doesn't break the laws of physics. I already wrote it. When you compile a different program, you cannot assume that the rest of the code stays the same. The variable might end up elsewhere on the stack, or the stack might end up with different values. If you really want to see what is going on, you'll have to look at the disassembled code for both variants, not just the source code. And this is exactly the point of undefined behavior. In the real world, it is not "undefined", it is undefined on one layer, but still defined by the layers below.

Comment: Because the not-well-know-yet random quantic nature of space-time added with Heisenberg's famous Uncertainty, makes the OS to provide a different memory address to glGetIntegerv each time it's asked for in different executions.